# High latencies against https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token endpoint with auth_code flow

Tags: google-oauth, google-openid, google-openidconnect

We are exstensively using Google Open ID Connect on our infrastructure for more than year and it worked well so far.

From yesterday we started expieriencing slow responses from https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token (pure round trip with DNS resolution) from inside a pod of GKE cluster. Does any one expierienced that? Part of the calls to this endpoint takes as much as 10s and causes other system parts to timeout.

Is there any status page for Google Open ID Connect provider? Like this for GCP: https://status.cloud.google.com/ ? Are there any release notes? We are using https://accounts.google.com/.well-known/openid-configuration to discover endpoints, which mean we should be using latest endpoints. We use auth code flow only.